# python- problem with fig.add_shape and add_annotation

Tags: python, plotly

I have written this code and it is not giving me the solution that want. Can anyone help me and tell me what mistake I am making ?

CODE:
[image]

```
    fig=px.line(df_italy,x='Date',y='infection_rate_italy')
    fig.add_shape(
        dict(
        `enter code here`type="line",
         x0=italy_lockdown_start_date,
         y0=0,
         x1=italy_lockdown_start_date,
         y1=df_italy['infection_rate_italy'].max(),
         line=dict(color='red',width=2)
    )
)
fig.add_annotation(
    dict(
        x= italy_lockdown_start_date,
        y=df_italy['infection_rate_italy'].max(),
        text='starting date of lockdown'
    )
)
fig.show()
```

my output:

[image]

the output that I am interested in is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would add hovertext when plotting the original line (following https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/)

```
fig = px.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['date'], # pls, modify accordingly
    y=df['n_cases'], # pls modify accordingly
    hovertemplate= "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" +
        "Date: %{x|%Y/%m/%d}<br>" +
        "Infection rate: %{y:.0%}<br>" +
        "Population: %{marker.size:,}" +
        "<extra></extra>"
        ))
```

Vertical lines part:

```
fig=px.line(df_italy,x='Date',y='infection_rate_italy')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[italy_lockdown_start_date, italy_lockdown_start_date],
    y=[0, df_italy['infection_rate_italy'].max()],
    mode="lines",
    line=go.scatter.Line(color="red"),
    showlegend=False))
fig.add_annotation(
    dict(
        x= italy_lockdown_start_date,
        y=df_italy['infection_rate_italy'].max(),
        text='starting date of lockdown'
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank-you so much for your help :)